# use scope method in blade

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have two tables: revisions_intervals and revisions. Revisions_intervals has many revisions and one revision belongs to one revisions_intervals.
So, i my revision model:

```
public function revision_interval() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Revision_interval');
}
```

and in my revision_interval model:

```
public function revisions() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Revision');
}
```

I have view "index" for revisions intervals, where for each one I want to show how many relations are related to specified revision interval. In my "index" blade:

```
@foreach($revision_intervals as $interval)
                <tr>
                    <td> 
                        {{ count($interval->revisions->past()) }} /
                        {{ count($interval->revisions) }} 
                    </td>
                </tr>
@endforeach
```

This "past()" method should be "scope" method for revision model, but this doesnt work. How to do it? ( Select specified revisions for collection )

I have "scopePast" method in my revision model:

```
public function scopePast($query) {
    $date = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');
    $query->where('date_of_revision', '>', $date);
}
```

Comment: Witch query did you to get the `$interval` befor passing it to the view ?

Comment: I get $revision_intervals by query: $revision_intervals = Revision_interval::all()

Comment: Try to do it like so `$revision_intervals = Revision_interval::with('revisions')->all()`

Comment: error: method "past" does not exist!

Comment: I think you shoul simlpy add `()` like this : `{{ count($interval->revisions()->past()) }}` try it :)